# How can I make a choice loop and only exit when numer 9 is put?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Geometry {

    private Scanner scanner;

    public double getCircleArea( double radius ) {
        System.out.print("Enter circle area");
        radius = scanner.nextDouble();
        double RadiusSquared = Math.pow(radius, 2);
        double circleArea =  RadiusSquared * Math.PI;
        return circleArea;
    }

    public double getRectangleArea( double length, double width ) {
        System.out.print("Enter rectangle Length");
        length = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter rectangle width");
        width = scanner.nextDouble();
        double rectangleArea = length * width;
        return rectangleArea;
    }

    public double getTriangleArea( double base, double height ) {
        System.out.println("enter triangle base");
        base = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter triangle height");
        height = scanner.nextDouble();
        double triangleArea = (base* height)/2;
        return triangleArea;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Geometry().go();
    }
    private void go() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // main processing logic including input and output goes here.
        int userNum = 0;
        int secNum = 0;
        while (userNum <= 0) {
            System.out.println("1. Area of circle\n" + "2. Area of rectangle\n" + "3. Area of triangle\n" + "9. Exit");
            userNum = scanner.nextInt();
            if (userNum == 1){
                System.out.println(getCircleArea(userNum));
            }
            else if (userNum == 2){
                System.out.println(getRectangleArea(userNum,secNum));
            }
            else if (userNum == 3){
                System.out.println(getTriangleArea(userNum,secNum));
            }
            else if (userNum == 9){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I wanted it to only be able to put these 4 numbers but I am not sure if this is better than just a while loop, which I think I know how to do. Also what do you think about the actual geometry?

Comment: You can use a break statement if the condition where you are checking for the number 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code and figure out what's problematic in your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Geometry {

    private Scanner scanner;

    public double getCircleArea( double radius ) {
        System.out.print("Enter radius of circle to find area: ");
        radius = scanner.nextDouble();
        double RadiusSquared = Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return RadiusSquared * Math.PI;
    }

    public double getRectangleArea( double length, double width ) {
        System.out.print("Enter rectangle Length: ");
        length = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter rectangle width: ");
        width = scanner.nextDouble();
        return length * width;
    }

    public double getTriangleArea( double base, double height ) {
        System.out.print("enter triangle base: ");
        base = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("enter triangle height: ");
        height = scanner.nextDouble();
        return (base*height)/2;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Geometry().go();
    }
    private void go() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // main processing logic including input and output goes here.
        int userNum = 0;
        int secNum = 0;
        while (userNum <= 0) {
            System.out.println("1. Area of circle\n" + "2. Area of rectangle\n" + "3. Area of triangle\n");
            System.out.print("choose a number: ");
            userNum = scanner.nextInt();
            if (userNum == 1) { System.out.println("Area of circle is " + getCircleArea(userNum)); }
            else if (userNum == 2){ System.out.println("Area of rectangle is " + getRectangleArea(userNum,secNum)); }
            else if (userNum == 3){ System.out.println("Area of triangle is " + getTriangleArea(userNum,secNum)); }
            else System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on what your needs.

- If you want to always display the menu selection bar once after user got the area, **while** is a must.
- If not, just use Map to map each user's selection as to avoid bunches of if else block

```
    //THIS IS FOR OPTION2

    //no need the parameter, radius is depending input in the method scope
    public double getCircleArea() {//...}
    //...
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Map<Integer, Func> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(num1, () -> getCircleArea());
       //map.put(num2, xxx()) etc
        new Geometry().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        //...
        map.get(userNum)
    }

    interface Func{
        void execute();
    }
```

(ps, from the code, seen `scanner.nextDouble()`, `scanner.nextInt()` to get from input of scanner. I think it is an alert when using different API to maintain the same functionality.
Because it violates encapsulation principle. java.util.Scanner already has the javadoc to interpret these, thus you should check from your side.
)